# Excel different interpretation

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

While I was following the steps as in the link, I noticed that the old Office Excel interpretaties formulas differently in comparison with the new Office Excel.

For example the , has to be ; instead. Also, the formulas are interpreted differently. Why and how? What do I have to change in the formula in the new Office Excel to make it work (see image).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993727/how-to-group-excel-items-based-on-custom-rules

[image: differences excels Microsoft and Google]

And instead of:

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("laptop",A2)),"laptop",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("notebook",A2)),"laptop",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("iphone",A2)),"phone",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("galaxy s",A2)),"phone","other"))))

or

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(G$2:G$5,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F$2:F$5,A2)),0)),"other")
```

or

something with VLOOKUP possible?

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: People with less then 10 reputation are not allowed to have images viewable in their post yet since it can be spam. These are the rules of the site please don't complain about this in your question. I've added your question and added the image.

Answer (score 2):

If your version of Excel requires formulas of the type:

```
=SUM(A1;B9)
```

rather than

```
=SUM(A1,B9)
```

Then you need to change your Regional Settings.